# Laravel route duplication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am working on building my first API. Currently, I have the following.

```php
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'AuthController@showLogin');
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']], function () {
        Route::resource('account', 'AccountController');
        Route::resource('notifications', 'NotificationController');
        Route::resource('contacts', 'ContactController');
    });
});
```

How can I make it that all requests to /api/v1 go to the API?

For future use, when I upgrade/add new features to an API going to `/api`, it's always the latest version. However, if a user goes to `api/v1/`, they use only version 1 of the API.

Comment: your details are not enough to understand that what you want to do, please elaborate little more

Comment: I basically want all request from api to redirect to api/v2 but still want api/v1 to still work. so basically people can have different version of the api so that as i make changes i don't break older apis. /api/ always goes to the latest version, unless a version is specified.